# Root dialog keeps repeating- BotBuilder Node.js

Tags: botframework

Firstly i code session.begin('chooseDay'), representing the first dialog. In this one, i send to the user one HeroCard with two buttons. When i press one button, i begin another dialog but before the results of the new dialogs the ones of the first(root) come up again. What is going wrong here?
[image: Step 1]
  **First Dialog(root dialog)**
[image: Step2]
**Second dialog,sends HeroCard,begins**

**[image: Step 3] Third Dialog**

Answer (score 1):

I cant see all your code, but I believe you would need to separate these into different functions in the waterfall.

For examples:

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, [(session) => 
{
   session.beginDialog('chooseDay');}, 
(session, results) => 
{
   session.send(msg); session.beginDialog('pharmacyToday')}, 
(session, results) => 
{ 
  session.endDialog(msg);
}]
```

This is shown in the documentation here [Manage conversation flow with dialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-manage-conversation-flow).

Hope that helps!